# Matching template argument template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a kind of key-value database. The specs of the item to write are stored in a template, let's say

```
template<int address, typename T>
class ItemInfo{};
```

i.e `ItemInfo<0x100, unsigned>` means that some item which is of type unsigned, will be stored at the address 0x100.

Now I want a write a method that effectively does the store. It should receive both an `ItemInfo` and a value, something like this

```
template<typename ItemInfo, typename T>
void store(T value);
```

Note that `ItemInfo` should be **a a template argument, not a function argument**. In that method I need to know what the `ItemInfo` address and template type `T` are, so I can accomplish two things;

1. To store the item at the address provided
2. To only store the provided value if its type is the same as the one
   provided by the `ItemsInfo` type.

So the question is, how could I write such `store` method?

Notes: I can use C++20.
The provided answer by @joergbrech is fine, but I wonder if there's a simpler solution, specially not involving concepts.

Comment: Just use a normal non-template function.

Comment: Do you have C++20 available?

Comment: @user12002570 yes

Comment: Can you also some use case. Like how would you want this to be usable. Since `T0` is arebitrary it is not clear when `T0` would be equal to `T`. Like **how do you want to call this function template?**

Comment: @user12002570 both `T0` and `T` are arbitrary, they will be equal if they are the same type.

Comment: Can you show how do you want to call this function template and when you want it to fail. That would make it more clear what you want. For example, you could add in your question some example calls which succeed and some which fails. Or do you want [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xnqj6KM8f)?

Comment: @user12002570 I don't want to pass E as a function parameter, but as a template parameter.

Comment: Ok show us how do you want to call this function template. And when do you want that call to fail. That is, show us expected the driver code also.

Comment: @user12002570 Sorry, I think it is clear enough. I don't see the need.

Comment: No it is not clear enough. It maybe to you because you posted the question. But unless you explicitly tell exactly how you want to call, it is not clear. We can't answer based on assumptions and guesses.

Comment: And really  your question is unclear for me too, I for example have no idea where your `T0` comes from. For us to be able to help it would really help if you would show a bit more code on how you want to use your function.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I just posted a question, and I politely refused to give details that I found unnecessary. There's no need to push. It may be unclear to you, that's fine, but that doesn't necessarily mean that the question is unclear, there can be other people that do not find it that way, as there's proof below. I'm posting questions to a community, not to a single user. And please, skip condescending remarks, they are not necessary.

Comment: @perencia And the community is clearly telling you that your question is not clear enough. The answer given below is based on one interpretation of your question. That doesn't prove that the question itself is clear. I can interpret your question another way and answer but that is not the purpose of Q&A here. Your question should be perfectly clear to the readers. That is, there should least(or none) amount of guesswork that readers have to do to answer your question. Unless you show how you expect your function template to be called and when you want it to fail, it will not be clear enough.

Comment: @user12002570 I think the question is clear enough. You don't think so, that's fine. Let's see if there's people that find it clear enough or not. I may be wrong. As I said, there's no need to push.

Comment: @perencia Ofcourse you think that. But that is not why you wrote the question. You wrote the question so that others can understand it and provide an answer. You're the OP so it is obviously clear to you. But a question is written so that other can clearly understand it as well and present an answer based on that. So that the question will help future readers as well. But since this question doesn't even attempt to explain the problem, it is not clear enough to the community.

Comment: @perencia Never shy from improving your question. It will only benefit the community.

Comment: @user12002570 I hope the question is clear enough now. If not, ask me whatever details you need.

Comment: @perencia: You can use my solution completely without the concept part. If you want to make sure that the template parameter passed into f is `E<T>` you can check using a `static_assert` instead. This would work with C++11 https://godbolt.org/z/4bhvheEr3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention that you have C++20 available, you could define a concept that checks if a type is a realization of your template E and require that the template parameter of your function satisifies this concept.

In addition, you need to be able to extract the template type of `E`. If you can modify `E`, you can add a typedef to `E` like so:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T0>
class E{
public:
    using type = T0;
};

// SFINAE to check if a type is a template realization of E
namespace details {
    template <typename T> struct is_E : std::false_type {};
    template <typename T> struct is_E<E<T>> : std::true_type {};
}
template <typename T> constexpr bool is_E_v = details::is_E<T>::value;

// concept for E<T>
template<typename T> concept is_E = requires { is_E_v<T>; };

// function requires template parameter to be E
template<is_E E>
void f(typename E::type val){};

int main()
{
    f<E<double>>(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9d3hc4WGG

If you cannot modify `E`, you can add some meta-programming to extract the type:

```cpp
// meta-programming to extract the template parameter of E
namespace details {
    template <typename T> struct E_value;
    template <typename T> struct E_value<E<T>> { using type = T; };
}
template <typename T> using E_value_type = typename details::E_value<T>::type;


// function requires template parameter to be E
template<is_E E>
void f(E_value_type<E> val){};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/GndM76M1n

---

**Addendum 1**

Here is a simplification, that does not require the definition of any additional meta-programming structs. You just need to provide an additional template parameter to `f`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T0>
class E{};

template <typename EType, typename T>
concept is_E_with_type = requires { std::is_same_v<EType, E<T>>; };

// function requires template parameter to be E
template<typename EType, typename T>
requires is_E_with_type<EType, T>
void f(T val){};

int main()
{
    f<E<double>>(2.0);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/6Y8bd75Y3

---

**Addendum 2**

If you don't like concepts or want to support older C++ standards, you could use `static_assert`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T0>
class E{};

// function requires template parameter to be E
template<typename EType, typename T>
void f(T val){
    static_assert(std::is_same<EType, E<T>>::value, "template parameter passed in is not a template realization of E.");
};

int main()
{
    f<E<double>>(2.0);
    //f<bool>(1); // static_assert fails
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nYjc3hT63